# Axios CORS issue between VueJS frontend and SailsJS backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cors, sails.js

I've thrown the kitchen sink at this problem yet I'm still unable to make an Axios connection from my VueJs frontend to my SailsJS backend. Vue is running on `localhost:8080` and Sails is running on `localhost:1337`. Here is the error message and some relevant settings -

[image]

*Vue - vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:1337',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/': ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Vue - src/views/Example.vue*

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'
  axios.defaults.crossDomain = true
  axios.defaults.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'


  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/hello')
```

*Sails - config/security.js*

```
module.exports.security = {

  cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
    headers: 'content-type',
    allowAnyOriginWithCredentialsUnsafe: true,
  }

};
```

*Sails - api/controllers/ExampleController.js*

```
module.exports = {
  hello: function(req, res) {
    return res.status(200).send('hello');
  }
}
```

I've tinkered with these settings a good amount based on other SO suggestions but nothing seems to get around this CORS error. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I found one solution that works, albeit not ideal. If I add this at the action level it will send a response that my frontend will accept.

*Sails - api/controllers/ExampleController.js*

```
module.exports = {
  hello: function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');

    return res.status(200).send('hello');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your sails config/routes.js, try:

```
'POST /api/v1/your_route': { action: 'your_path_to_action', cors: false, csrf: false },
```

And why is your axios default, `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'` set to :8080?

Comment: I tried adding `cors` and `csrf` at the route level too and that didn't work unfortunately. It looks like the issue is the response from Sails doesn't have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the header, and the only way to fix that I found was to add it at the action level. I updated my question with the fix. Unfortunately I think I would have to do that for every action which is not ideal. The `axios.defaults.baseURL` was just copy and paste code that I tried temporarily, I took it out now.

Comment: to me it works like this 

```cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: [
      'https://example.com:1337',
      'https://another_domain.com',
      'http://an_IP’
    ],
    allowRequestHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With,, Accept',
    allowRequestMethods: 'GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,OPTIONS,DELETE,HEAD',
    allowCredentials: true,
  },```


 Note: sorry it didn't keep formatting...

Comment: it still isn't working for me unfortunately. It has to be some config setting that I set somewhere that I'm just forgetting about and it's conflicting with those settings. That's the only thing I can think of.